# Rails Devise Omniauth omniauth_openid_connect issue; Always getting `Not found. Authentication passthru`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, openid-connect

sorry if I am missing something very basic but I think I need some help in configuring `omniauth_openid_connect` gem (https://github.com/m0n9oose/omniauth_openid_connect/) with devise in my application; I am always getting `Not found. Authentication passthru`. error;

The url that devise upon clicking 'Sign In with OpenIdConnect' goes to is: https://myapp.com/users/auth/openid_connect

My config looks like below in `config/initializers/devise.rb` :

```
config.omniauth :openid_connect, 
{ 
    name: :openid_connect,
    scope: [:openid],
    response_type: :code,
    client_options:
    {
    port: 443,
    scheme: "https",
    host: "staging-oauth.provider.com",
    issuer: "https://staging-oauth.provider.com",
    authorization_endpoint: "/oauth2/auth", 
    token_endpoint: "/oauth2/token", 
    identifier: 'CLIENT_ID', 
    secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET', 
    redirect_uri: "https://myapp.com/users/auth/openid_connect/callback", 
    }, 
    }
```

I know I have added extra parameters in it but that's because I'm unsure of what exactly is required; I cant see any logs on the server as well so it means I am not hitting the correct endpoint or something

I have the following urls from provider available

issuer endpoint (https://staging-oauth.provider.com)

authorization endpoint (https://staging-oauth.provider.com/oauth2/auth)

token endpoint (https://staging-oauth.provider.com/oauth2/token)

also I have the client id and secret

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 3):

The correct config:

```
config.omniauth :openid_connect, 
{ 
    name: :openid_connect,
    scope: [:openid],
    issuer: "https://staging-oauth.provider.com/"
    response_type: :code,
    discovery: :true,
    client_options:
    {
    port: 443,
    scheme: "https",
    host: "staging-oauth.provider.com",
    authorization_endpoint: "/oauth2/auth", 
    token_endpoint: "/oauth2/token", 
    identifier: 'CLIENT_ID', 
    secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET', 
    redirect_uri: "https://myapp.com/users/auth/openid_connect/callback", 
    }, 
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the boilerplate for Devise controllers & callbacks?

Comment: I think this link may be helpful https://github.com/betagouv/civilsdeladefense/pull/782/files